# Cannot set the properties of eclipse blackberry plugin

Tags: eclipse, jar, eclipse-plugin, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have installed blackberry plugin for eclipse successfully from [here](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/downloads/eclipseplugin/).However when I try to edit preferences eclispe gives error and I think I found the problem but don't know how to fix it.The problem is Caused by:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.qnx.tools.bbt.core.sdk.IBlackBerryTabletSDKDescriptor.IRegistry.Impl.Priority.HİGH, it converts Capital I to İ -is a Turkish character- from the enum value HIGH.
```

Is there any way to fix it.My System is Win 7 64 bit Turkish.
Session data from the log;

```
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.7.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=tr_TR
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86
```

Full error log is ;

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.rim.ajde.ui.preferences.AndroidPreferencePage.getDefaultSSHKeyPath(AndroidPreferencePage.java:232)
    at net.rim.ajde.preferences.PreferenceInitializer.initializeDefaultPreferences(PreferenceInitializer.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper$1.run(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.runInitializer(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.applyRuntimeDefaults(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.applyRuntimeDefaults(PreferencesService.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.applyRuntimeDefaults(DefaultPreferences.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.load(DefaultPreferences.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:631)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.AbstractScope.getNode(AbstractScope.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences.DefaultScope.getNode(DefaultScope.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore.getDefaultPreferences(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore.getPreferenceNodes(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore.internalGet(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore.getBoolean(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.BooleanFieldEditor.doLoad(BooleanFieldEditor.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.FieldEditor.load(FieldEditor.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.FieldEditorPreferencePage.initialize(FieldEditorPreferencePage.java:307)
    at net.rim.ajde.ui.preferences.PreferencePage.initialize(PreferencePage.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.FieldEditorPreferencePage.createContents(FieldEditorPreferencePage.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferencePage.createControl(PreferencePage.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createPageControl(PreferenceDialog.java:1501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$14.run(PreferenceDialog.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.showPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1252)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.showPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$10.run(PreferenceDialog.java:708)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$9.selectionChanged(PreferenceDialog.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:886)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1226)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$5.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$5(OpenStrategy.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$3.run(OpenStrategy.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.open(WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.ShowPreferencePageHandler.execute(ShowPreferencePageHandler.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.qnx.tools.bbt.core.sdk.IBlackBerryTabletSDKDescriptor.IRegistry.Impl.Priority.HİGH
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at com.qnx.tools.bbt.core.sdk.IBlackBerryTabletSDKDescriptor$IRegistry$Impl$Priority.valueOf(IBlackBerryTabletSDKDescriptor.java:1)
    at com.qnx.tools.bbt.core.sdk.IBlackBerryTabletSDKDescriptor$IRegistry$Impl$Priority.getPriority(IBlackBerryTabletSDKDescriptor.java:403)
    at com.qnx.tools.bbt.core.sdk.IBlackBerryTabletSDKDescriptor$IRegistry$Impl$Reader.doAdd(IBlackBerryTabletSDKDescriptor.java:358)
    at com.qnx.tools.bbt.core.utils.RegistryReader.add(RegistryReader.java:134)
    at com.qnx.tools.bbt.core.utils.RegistryReader.handleAdd(RegistryReader.java:117)
    at com.qnx.tools.bbt.core.utils.RegistryReader.readRegistry(RegistryReader.java:91)
    at com.qnx.tools.bbt.core.sdk.IBlackBerryTabletSDKDescriptor$IRegistry$Impl.<init>(IBlackBerryTabletSDKDescriptor.java:192)
    at com.qnx.tools.bbt.core.sdk.IBlackBerryTabletSDKDescriptor$IRegistry.<clinit>(IBlackBerryTabletSDKDescriptor.java:153)
    ... 85 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a bug report on the Blackberry plugin. This looks like typical outcome when [not specifying the encoding needed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/stream.html) to correctly read some stream. In such cases Java uses the default encoding, which in your case is Turkish and therefore [differs in the interpretation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aTurkish_characters) of some byte to character conversions, compared to whatever they used when developing the Blackberry plugin.